# Is there a way to overlay a remote kmz file in google maps

Tags: google-maps, overlay, kmz

I have a kmz file and want to overlay it on google maps. What I'm searching for is sth. like: `https://www.google.de/maps?kmz=server/tour.kmz`

I've already checked the query [params](http://asnsblues.blogspot.co.at/2011/11/google-maps-query-string-parameters.html) for google maps, but couldn't find one for this purpose.

I don't want to upload and connect that kmz file with my google account.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already used a KmlLayer

see this google developer sample

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml